# backbone.js: Button in view that affects a different model in collection

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I'm just getting going with backbone.js.  So far, I'm really liking it.

I have something like this:

- ModelA
- ModelB
- ViewA
- ViewB

ModelA holds a collection of ModelB

How can I build a ViewB of ModelB with a button which, when clicked, changes an attribute on the next ModelB instance in the collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var col = this.model.collection;
var nextModel = col.at( col.indexOf(this.model) + 1)
if(nextModel) nextModel.set({whatevar});
```

You do not need to keep track of the parent collection, backbone does it for you. 
You should check if you are at the end of the collection also.

Comment: Love it.  The backbone.js picture just keeps getting clearer and clearer to me.  It's obviously made by people who've thought things through and who've put their work to the test on real solutions.  Thanks.

Comment: Is this in the documentation?  I can't find it.

Comment: Well this is in the code. You can read the annotated version here http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html  small caveat if you add your model to more than 1 collection, only the last one will be referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured something out.  I'll share to see what others think so that others can benefit.

I simply pass in a reference to the parent collection to each model in the collection.

Inside my collection, when adding a new instance:

```
var newModelBInstance = new ModelB( { id: "xxx", ParentCollection: this } );
```

And then, inside my ModelB view:

```
this.model.get("ParentCollection").at(this.model.sortValue + 1).set({ myAttr: false });
```