# backbone.js: How can I access the parent model of a nested collection?

Tags: collections, models, backbone.js

I have a model, let's call it "modelA", which has a nested "collectionX" of say "modelB".

- modelA

  - collectionX (modelB)

When working with a modelB instance, I can easily access its siblings or its [collection's meta data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930656/setting-attributes-on-a-collection-backbone-js) using [`this.collection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889198/backbone-js-button-in-view-that-affects-a-different-model-in-collection).

How can I access attributes of the parent model (modelA)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no default way to do this is backbone. Just add the modelA attribute to the collection and access it within modelB.

Answer (score 1):

Beware that in some cases it does make sense to add a model to multiple collections.  In such cases what would the parent be?  Likewise, what would `collection` be?  The last one to which the model was added, right?

Right now, backbone is not equipped to handle having a model belong to multiple collections--that is, having multiple parents.